# Can not use the `this` in my callback function

Tags: javascript, callback

I have a Util method:

```
util.delete_selection = function (context, delete_url_func, selection, cb=undefined) { ... }
```

and when I use the `delete_selection` method, I pass the `cb` like bellow, there will get a issue, I can not in the callback function to use the `this`:

```
Util.delete_selection(
      this,
      this.delete_url_function,
      this.selection,
      function (bool) {
        debugger
        this.$emit('callback')   // there the `this` is undefined.
        console.log('cb')
      }
    )
```

And I tried use the arrow function to replace it, find it can not use the arrow function there.

---

**EDIT**

When I use the arrow function like bellow, the WebStorm will report error there:

[image]

If I change the bool to other param name, it still get error:

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access the correct \`this\` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since, `this` gives the reference of the container inside which it is being used, when you use `this` inside `callback` it gives you the scope of the `callback` function and not the parent function. Thus, you can bind `this` in the `callback` as:

```
Util.delete_selection(
      this,
      this.delete_url_function,
      this.selection,
      function (bool) {
        this.$emit('callback')
        console.log('cb')
      }.bind(this)
    )
```

Comment: thank you, this solved my problem, but why i can not use the arrow function?

Comment: i wonder who downvoted mine. it essentially explains this quite well too.

Comment: the time is not yet, there is a interval.

Comment: Tell me whether is your download the @GottZ 's answer?

Comment: @sof-03 why should I downvote his answer? As his answer and mine answer is completely different.

Comment: @sof-03 you can also do upvote to mark it as useful.

Answer (score 0):

you might want to replace
`function (bool) {`
with
`bool => {`

but since you don't even use `bool` itself, you could omit it and write: `() => {` instead.

#### why?

that's a lambda. it does not have it's own context.
`function` however has.
`this` inside `function` blocks always refer to the `function` scope and not the scope of the upper layer.

you can always override the context of a function using either `.bind(context)` to cause a rebind or use `.call(context, ...arguments)` or `.apply(context, [...arguments])` but a lambda would probably be a good idea here.

---

using a lambda should actually work here. just run this and you see it in action:

```js
const data = [{
  some: 'thing',
  text: 'foo'
}, {
  some: 'thing else',
  text: 'bar'
}];

const doSomething = function (arg, func) {
  console.log('some:', arg.some);
  func();
};

data.map(context => {
  (function () {
    
    doSomething(this, () => {
      console.log('text:', this.text);
    });
    
  }).call(context);
});
```

Comment: hi, bro, see my EDIT, why I use the `bool => {}` will report error?

Comment: hm. maybe your webstorm setup does not allow es6 javascript yet. wich is weird since all browsers do.

Comment: just replace `bool` with `()` and see if that works.

Comment: it seems like webstorm thinks `bool` is a reserved word

Comment: just added a snippet. seems to work as intended. you might want to figure out why webstorm is giving you a bad day.

Answer (score 0):

`this` in javascript is a bit confusing. Have a look: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

You need to bind this to the callback

```js
Util.delete_selection(
      this,
      this.delete_url_function,
      this.selection,
      function (bool) {
        debugger
        this.$emit('callback')   // there the `this` is undefined.
        console.log('cb')
      }.bind(this)
    )
```